# Make table rows in Microsoft Word Online autosize according to content?

Tags: table-styles, page-layout-view, office-live

How do you do set heights for rows in Tables that much like HTML tables will not crop content, but adapt to the actual space the content needs? In Word Online, not Excel Online.

I have no idea what the development lead members were thinking making this an obscure action. Can you even set a height of rows?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, it needs to add more Tags related to the appropriate topic like MS-Excel. Excel-Online.

Comment: It's not about Excel, online or otherwise! It's about Word-online! Added the "office-live" tag as there is no tag for that. There's no "Excel-Online" tag either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word Online does not have the capability to set row height properties for tables. You have to use a desktop version of Word to do that.

For tables added to a document using Word Online, the default is to allow rows to expand in height based on the content entered into cells within the rows.

If the table you are working with in a document you are editing was originally created using a desktop version of Word and it has a fixed height setting for the rows, you can only modify that setting by using a desktop version of the application.